# Spectral Density Estimators

Tags: time-series, mathematical-statistics, spearman-rho, spectral-analysis

I'm interested in showing that if we allow the kernel $h$ defined by 
$$h((x_1,y_1)^T,(x_2,y_2)^T,(x_3,y_3)^T)=\frac{1}{6}\sum_{\gamma \in \Gamma\{1,2,3\}}[12I(x_{\gamma(1)}<x_{\gamma(2)},y_{\gamma(1)}<y_{\gamma{(3)}})-3],$$

we obtain the (lag $k$) population version of Spearman's $\rho$, that is

$$\rho=3(\mathbb{P}[(X_0^{(1)}-X_0^{(2)})(X_k^{(1)}-X_k^{(3)})>0]-\mathbb{P}[(X_0^{(1)}-X_0^{(2)})(X_k^{(1)}-X_k^{(3)})<0])$$

by

$$\xi_k=\mathbb{E}\left[ h \left((X_0^{(1)},X_k^{(1)})^T,\ldots ,(X_0^{(m)},X_{k}^{(m)})^T  \right) \right]$$

We can assume the following:

Let $\{X_t\}_{t\in \mathbb{Z}}$ be a real-valued process and denote $F$ and $F_k$ the marginal distribution function of $X_t$ and the distribution of the pair $(X_t, X_{t+k})$ respectively $(k \in \mathbb{Z})$. $\{X_t\}_{t \in \mathbb{Z}}$ is strictly stationary, the functions $F$ and $F_k$ are continuous (for all $k \in \mathbb{Z}$) and that $\sum_{k \in \mathbb{Z}} \vert \xi_k \vert < \infty$. Moreover, $(X_1,Y_1),(X_2,Y_2)$ are independent copies with the same distribution as $(X_0,X_k)$

Comment: If this is a self-study question, please consider adding the corresponding tag.